# "Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon..." error prevents reboot / shut down while logged in

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I am not able to shutdown or reboot;  I get the following error.

```
 * Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Stopping ADC hub uhub
Checking for running unattended upgrades:
Stopping Webmin server in usr/share/webmin
 * Stopping the Winbind daemon winbind
 * Stopping bluetooth<br>
... waiting  * Stopping web server apache2
 * Will now halt
[29856.516087] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Queue 9 stuck for 2000 ms.
[29856.516191] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: On demand firmware reload
[29861.533613] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[29861.533718] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[29861.533867] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
```

[image]

It happens if any user tries it after logging in.

If I don't login at the lightdm screen on power on and execute shutdown or reboot I can.

However, if I login even from a remote terminal I can't reboot.

Comment: Looks like that it's hanging on the wireless device. What kind of Wireless card do you have?  What version of Ubuntu? Out of curiosity if you disable your wifi prior to shutdown/reboot, does the computer properly poweroff?

Comment: I have a Dell N7010 Running Ubuntu 11.10 64 Bit ,,, The Card is Intel Wimax + Wireless-N  6250

Answer (score 4):

这个问题我之前也遇到过，可以选择Ubuntu启动盘启动，选择修复模式可以更正系统出现的一些硬件不能驱动的问题。

Google Translate:

> I had also encountered this problem, you can choose
>   the Ubuntu boot disk, select repair mode can correct some of the
>   hardware system can not be driven.

Comment: can i use the recovery from the installed OS or use a the Ubuntu ISO